# Sending SGD command to Zebra printer and receiving the response with Java

Tags: java, printing, zpl

I'm working on Java application which prints label on Zebra printer. I've been using ZPL language and Java printing API till now, but ZPL is not suffiecient for my further works. The next thing I need to do is (programatically) checking if font with specified name is already installed on the printer. I've found that I may achieve my goal with SGD commands. But I have no idea how to send it from Java application and get the response. The command I would like to send is

`! U1 do "file.dir" "R:"`

Has anybody met similar problem? The printer is connected with computer via USB. Is it possible to use Java printing API to send the command and receive answer or maybe I should use sockets or something completely different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SGDs like that need to be terminated with a `\r\n`.

Also, [Zebra provides a Java API](http://www.zebra.com/content/zebra/us/en/products-services/software/link-os/link-os-sdk.html) to ease communications with Zebra printers. There's a bunch of Javadoc and example code that comes with the download

Comment: I need a multiplatform solution, and the SDK's readme file says that it supports "PC Operating systems using Java Runtime Environment (JRE) v1.6+", but in real it does not. It looks like the Zebra Java API only works on Windows machines. A ConnectionException is thrown during getting list of USB printers on Linux (with message "Invalid OS").

Comment: The USB connections are driver based which only exist in windows. TCP would work in linux. Or you could extend the connection and do it over CUPS or native linux usb if you like

Answer (score 2):

I know this is very old topic, but I found this during my research few days ago and I just figured out a different approach.
This answer might help others finding their answers :)

Opening a simple connection to the printer on port 9100 for each command it works fine.

example send SDG commands to a zebra zt410 trough a raw tcp-ip connection:

```
# get current state of telnet
echo '! U getvar "ip.telnet.enable"' | nc <printerIP> 9100
#Response received: "on"

# send disable telnet command
echo '! U1 setvar "ip.telnet.enable" "off"' | nc <printerIP> 9100
# No response received.

# get current state of telnet
echo '! U getvar "ip.telnet.enable"' | nc <printerIP> 9100
# Response received: "off"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I do not have access to Zebra printer any longer, so can't check the solution out. However, thank you for the answer.